# Deploy war in Jboss - MAVEN

Tags: deployment, jboss, build, maven

I just migrated from ant to maven .. and i successfully created a war from 3 module . But now i want my war to be deployed automatically into jboss server. Is there any plugin or So

help appreciated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [Cargo](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Home) plugin. It supports [hot deployment to containers](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Deploying+to+a+running+container).

Comment: Link is dead. (Sorry Zelda)